# Django - pre_delete signal not updating instance's foreign key field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-signals

I am trying to use a `pre_delete` signal for the `Like` model of my Django app. The `Like` model has a `Book` foreign key. The `Book` model has a `num_of_likes` field. Ultimately, I am trying to update this `num_of_likes` field from my `pre_delete` signal. Just I couldn't do it.

My code will make what the problem is very clear, I think (please pay special attention to the comments and print statements):

books/**models.py**:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    num_of_likes = models.IntegerField()
```

likes/**models.py**:

```
class Like(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book)
```

likes/**views.py**:

```
class DeleteLikeView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, book):
        book = get_object_or_404(Book, id=book)
        print(book.num_of_likes) # Prints, say, 10
        like = Like.objects.get(user=request.user, book=book)
        like.delete() # triggers signal handler below (should update `book.num_of_likes`)
        print(book.num_of_likes) # Still prints 10, expected 9 <------ PROBLEM
        return ...
```

likes/**signals.py**:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Like)
def delete_book_like(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print(instance.book.num_of_likes) # Prints 10
    instance.book.num_of_likes -= 1
    instance.book.save()
    print(instance.book.num_of_likes) # Prints 9, as expected
```

Why does `book.num_of_likes` get updated inside `delete_book_like` but then changes don't show up in `DeleteLikeView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `book` in your delete view is a different **Python object** than the `instance.book` in your signal handler. The Python object does not magically learn that the underlying db representation has changed. You could call `refresh_from_db` before printing:

```
 book.refresh_from_db()
 print(book.num_of_likes)
```

Or just make `num_of_likes` an dynamically evaluated property altogether and you won't have to worry about the integrity of your denormalized data:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    @property
    def num_of_likes(self):
        return self.like_set.count()
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Could you point me to some documentation regarding the @property decorator you suggested? Thanks

Comment: [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) always a good start. You might also be interested in [django's cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property)